# Infinite loop: Haar, LBP, HOG traincascade of opencv stuck

Tags: opencv, face-detection, haar-classifier, cascade-classifier

I am trying to build a classifier to detect faces in Thermal images. So I tried training using Haar, LBP and HOG classifiers. I am working with OpenCV 2.4.8 on windows.

> `opencv_traincascade.exe -data haarcascades -vec pos.vec -bg neg.txt -numPos 250 -numStages 24 -numNeg 900 -w 24 -h 24`

I have 307 positive samples in total. The negative samples are of size 75x75. For each of the three cases the training gets stuck at a particular stage-earlier for Haar (stage-12) and later for LBP (stage-14/15). I reduced the number of negatives (upto 200) but that means the training gets stuck at a later stage. The training hasn't progressed since 2 days. No negatives are being consumed and the command window looks like this-

```
===== TRAINING 14-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   255 : 262
```

Also

- What do POS count consumed and NEG count consumed signify?
- When I reduce the minHitRate to say 0.7 why do the number of POS consumed increase?

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the similar problem myself. The thing is that classifier at each stage takes those negative examples which are classified as positive in the previous stages. So the thing that happens is that none of the negative samples are classified as positive and the code goes in the infinite loop trying to find one. I solved this by changing the source code so that the algorithm terminates after it cant find any negative example and just use the previous stages for the classifier. 
If you dont want to change the code try adding more negative examples or reducing the number of stages.

Answer (score 2):

Count consumed is the amount of possitve and negative images that are used in each stages. And you need to use more possitive and negatives images around 1000 positives and 2000 negative to get a good result